# Can I display font-awesome icons in html5 notifications

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome, html5-notifications

I was trying to display desktop notifications on my website.As per this documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/notification), I can provide a URL to the icon image.But my website is using font awesome icons, therefore I do not have a URL for icons.Any help or alternatives will be appreciated

```
function spawnNotification(theBody,theIcon,theTitle) {
  var options = {
      body: theBody,
      icon: theIcon //this should be a URL can I provide an icon class of a text content?
  }
  var n = new Notification(theTitle,options);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fontawesome icons does come in png, you can directly use a URL to the icon image.
You can host your images on your server

```
function spawnNotification(theBody,theIcon,theTitle) {
  var options = {
      body: theBody,
      icon: 'http://yourdomain.com/icons/icon.png'
  }
  var n = new Notification(theTitle,options);
}
```

For more info about the icons refer [here](http://www.flaticon.com/packs/font-awesome)

Comment: Thanks Saurabh! , that's a good idea.Unfortunately,  I can not follow this way because this application have thousands of font awesome icons and I have to support all the icons in the desktop notification.It is not practical to download all the font awesome icons in png format. I appreciate your efforts

Comment: Well @AbleJohnson, this might help https://github.com/encharm/Font-Awesome-SVG-PNG/tree/master/black/png